# Matplotlib contour hatching not working if only two levels was used

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, statistics

I am trying to plot hatches over contours lines that 
statisfy certian criteria folliwng the example found [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_hatching.html). Yet, I got regular contours (the yellow lines) instead of the hatches. Any ideas how to resolve that. Thanks
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# invent some numbers, turning the x and y arrays into simple
# 2d arrays, which make combining them together easier.
x = np.linspace(-3, 5, 150).reshape(1, -1)
y = np.linspace(-3, 5, 120).reshape(-1, 1)
z = np.cos(x) + np.sin(y)

# we no longer need x and y to be 2 dimensional, so flatten them.
x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
n_levels = 6
a=ax2.contourf(x, y, z, n_levels)
fig2.colorbar(a)
[m,n]=np.where(z > 0.5)
z1=np.zeros(z.shape)
z1[m,n]=99
cs = ax2.contour(x, y, z1,2,hatches=['','.'])
plt.show()enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `contourf()` with proper parameters to get useful plot with hatching. See important comment within the working code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3, 5, 150).reshape(1, -1)
y = np.linspace(-3, 5, 120).reshape(-1, 1)
z = np.cos(x) + np.sin(y)

x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
n_levels = 6
a = ax2.contourf(x, y, z, n_levels)

fig2.colorbar(a)
[m,n] = np.where(z > 0.5)

z1=np.zeros(z.shape)
z1[m, n] = 99

# use contourf() with proper hatch pattern and alpha value
cs = ax2.contourf(x, y, z1 ,3 , hatches=['', '..'],  alpha=0.25)

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I am wondering why we need to set the number of levels to 3. I found that it also work if I set the number of levels to 1 but not working with number of levelve equal to  2. Any idea what cause that.

Comment: Actually if you use `hatches=['|', '-', '.', '..','//','\\']`, any levels from 1 to 5 will produce hatching on the plots. The inclusion of blank quote ('') as one item in the `hatches` list specifying that you need no hatching at relating contour ranges, so it  causes no hatching in some situation as you found.

Comment: thanks. I added the following two lines that create a legend for the contour set           
    `artists, labels = cs.legend_elements() ` 
    `ax2.legend(artists, labels, handleheight=2)`                                                           and now I can see which values are represented by the hatches.